# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException radius must be > 0

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, illegalargumentexception, radial-gradients

Can anyone help me to find the reason behind this error??.I could not figure out the actual problem.The app is not crashing on my phone but after i updated the app on play store i got error report from crashlytics that the app is crashing on some other phones because of this error.I have used a gradient.xml as a drawable to set gradient for a cardview and another layout,please see my gradient.xml, below i could not find any error within this file.Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException radius must be > 0 

android.graphics.RadialGradient. (RadialGradient.java:53)
android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.buildShadowCorners    (Unknown Source)
android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.setBackground (Unknown Source)
android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.draw (Unknown Source)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:14707)
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw (FrameLayout.java:534)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13588)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13635)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:14430)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3252)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild (Unknown Source)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3070)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:14739)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw (Unknown Source)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13588)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13635)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:14430)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3252)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3070)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13580)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13635)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:14430)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3252)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3070)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:14739)
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw (FrameLayout.java:534)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13588)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13635)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:14430)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3070)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13580)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:13635)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:14430)
```

gradient.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="@null"
    android:startColor="#B3000000"
    android:type="linear"/>

<corners
    android:radius="1dp"/>
```

Comment: I'm sure it is because of `android:endColor="@null"`. What do you want to achieve with this line? It doesn't make any sense for me to use gradient with a start color and without end color

Comment: @Vlad Matveinko :Thanx for the reply. Can i set the gradient without an end color attribute ?

Comment: it will be a solid color, not a gradient if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove your android:endColor="@null",  if you dont want to have color just dont add it. or try transparent color.